# Change the default program to open .bat files

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, batch-file, file-association

I want to change the default program to open .bat files to `cmder` , so in the registry key : `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command` I did as following :

[image]

But when I open some .bat file I get the following error :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

## Edit :

I changed the registry key value to : `C:\Dev\Cmdr\Cmder.exe "%1"`

But I get this message whenever I open some batch file:

> The directory name is invalid.

[image]

Comment: "some" `.bat` files or all of them? Anything in particular about the bat files or their location?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes around the %1, otherwise paths with blanks in them arrvie as separate parameters: `...cmder “%1”`

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

I tried with ConEmu. I appended this string to the existing:

```
C:\(path_to_app)\ConEmu64.exe "%1" %*
```

The last part (`"%1" %*`) was there before the edit.

So I think you need to add `%*` after your whole string value in regedit (in your case): `C:\Dev\Cmdr\Cmder.exe "%1" %*`